# skype log out when screen lock in ubuntu 14.04 gnome

Tags: locking, screen, ubuntu-14.04, gnome-3

When I lock screen in Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 LTS it logs out from skype account.
I would like it not.
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not used with Ubuntu but in Windows this problem can occur when the power management makes the network connection to be closed when the pc is locked. Take a look over the network configurations in order to not allow the computer to close it.